# ap-hotspot wifi connection

Tags: wireless

i have created a wifi connection using ap-hotspot that can be accessed by android devices. The problem is, it stops whenver the terminal command is put on background. can anyone help me with this issue? What is the refreshing time of ap-hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a python daemon to solve this problem:

https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd

It depends on hostapd to do the actual provisioning, so you need to install that first. In theory, it should work on any major linux distro (though I've only tried on the `buntus - 12.04 & 14.04 yet)

To install:

```
wget https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd/raw/master/dist/hotspotd-0.1.tar.gz
tar xvf hotspotd-0.1.tar.gz
cd hotspotd-0.1/
sudo python setup.py install
```